# Random point inside SVG <path>

Tags: svg, path, geometry

The problem is really simple to describe. I have a simple SVG  closed shape, like this:

```
<path d="M435.95,147.99l0.33,0.49l-0.11,1.07l-0.39,0.04l-0.29,-0.15l0.21,-1.4l0.25,-0.05Z"></path>
```

I want to draw a point at random, somewhere inside this shape.

How to do that? I am hoping for a solution to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Is your shape guaranteed convex, or could it have concave regions?

Comment: I edited your title from _"on SVG `<path>`"_ (which is simple) to _"inside SVG `<path>`"_, since you wrote that in the question. If you really want just a random point along the border of the shape, please edit it back.

Comment: Could be concave. Thanks for the edit, you are correct, if I wanted just a point along the border, I would have used getPointAtLength() with random number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [getBBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) to get the bounding box of the path and generate a random point in that range. Then use [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) with the random point to check that you really are over the shape.

If any elements cover the path then set them to pointer-events="none" so that they are ignored when you do this.

Comment: That is a great idea, just the part of verifying intersection is a little bit "hackish". Sometimes the required element is not in the viewport of the browser, or, as in my case, there might be a random element covering the object. Let's say we have a web app, where user might place a window over.

Comment: The method above does not rely on it being in the viewport of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If the path is a convex , we can do it in a simply way:

```
Raphael.el.getRandomPointInsideConvex=function(){
    if(this.type!='path') return undefined;

    //sample two points along the path
    var len=this.getTotalLength(),
        p1=this.getPointAtLength(Math.random()*len),
        p2=this.getPointAtLength(Math.random()*len),
        ratio=Math.random();

    //get the random point
    var x=p1.x+(p2.x-p1.x)*ratio,
        y=p1.y+(p2.y-p1.y)*ratio;

    return {x:x,y:y};
};
```

You can call the method this way:

```
//el is an element
var r=el.getRandomPointInsideConvex();
//draw a cross at this point to show it.
el.paper.path(['M',r.x-2,r.y,'L',r.x+2,y,'M',r.x,r.y-2,'L',r.x,r.y+2]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good idea. For the future readers, I want to warn you that this solutions does not produce uniform selection. This means that points from certain areas have higher probability of being selected.

Comment: The accepted answer will loop as many times as needed for a truly random point in the bounding box to fall inside the shape. In contrast, this answer requires no looping, i.e. it requires only one pass. Thus, this solution could be faster than the accepted answer in a few edge cases, e.g. an extremely narrow oval at 45 degrees, where most random points in the bounding box will _not_ be inside the shape. However, the accepted answer is not limited to convex shapes while this answer is (and, as @Rok Kralj pointed out, this answer will actually not really have a truly random point within it).